# i could not set up babel-cli package globally installed via yarn?

Tags: linux, command-line

I need to set environmental variable for the babel-cli, i know the path however I could not set up. here is the path:

```
~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-cli/bin
```

inside this folder there are 4 files. i need to run babel.js via babel command.

```
export babel=~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel
```

this is the first thing i considered. then i slightly changed the path. for example, I replaced ~ with home, i omitted . from .config, i appended js to babel, babel.js, and more but I could not get it done.

I installed babel-cli locally yet I got same error:

```
 bash: babel: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [yarn global documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/global/), you should add a special `bin` folder to `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

If you add this statement to the appropriate initialization file (like `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or whatever), you’ll be able to use globally installed packages’ commands from anywhere without further configuration.

Comment: I run this code: yarn global bin and i got this: /home/yilmaz/.yarn/bin, then I added this: export babel="/home/yilmaz/.yarn/bin:babel" to the .bashrc file but it is not set. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t run anything. Add the exact line I wrote above. Otherwise you will break stuff. Also, for the changes to take effect, you need to re-open the shell.

Comment: you the man. i hope anything u touch turns to bitcoin for u